# Xamarin Forms and Calendar in c#

Tags: file, xamarin, text, calendar

I use to Xamarin Calendar my project of C#.

https://github.com/lilcodelab/Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar

I want to mark several undefined dates, because I want to download them from a text file

Example file:
5/5/2020|Name

Comment: What is your question?  You have just given us your requirements.  Where are you stuck?  What specific problem are you having?  Please see [ask] for help in writing a high quality question

Comment: As I add several dates, because in the documentation it only indicates fixed dates

Comment: just dynamically create an event add it to the EventCollection

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the **Binding events** part, the event is bind with **Events** collection, you could create several event object like:

```
 MyEvent event1=new MyEvent(name,description);
 MyEvent event2=new MyEvent(name,description);
```

and add them into the list:

```
events.add(event1);
events.add(event2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it this way

```
enter code here
   String path = @"actividades.txt";
   var filePath = Path.Combine(DEFAULTPATH, path);
   string texto1;
   System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
   Events = new EventCollection();
   while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
         texto1 = sr.ReadLine();
         string[] words = texto1.Split('|');
         DateTime fecha = DateTime.Parse(words[0]);
         d = fecha.Day;
         m = fecha.Month;
         y = fecha.Year;
         if (words.Length > 2)
         Events.Add(new DateTime(y, m, d), new List<Evento> { new Evento { Nombre = words[2], Tipo = words[1], colorF = words[3] } });
        }
```